# Python Library - json to json transformations

Tags: python, json, transformation, velocity

Does anyone know of a python library to convert JSON to JSON in an XSLT/Velocity template style?

JSON + transformation template = JSON (New)

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Sorry if it's old, but you can use this module https://github.com/Onyo/jsonbender
Basically it transform a dicc to another Dicc object using a mapping. What you can do is to dump the json into a dicc, transform it to another dicc and then transfrom it back to a json.

Answer (score 2):

I have not found the transformer library suitable for my needs and spend couple of days trying to create my own. And then I realized that creating transformation scheme is more difficult than writing native python code that transforms one json-like python object to another.

I understand, that this is not the answer to original question. And I also understand that my approach has certain limitations. F.e. if you need to generate documentation it wouldn't work.

But if you just need to transform json-like objects consider the possibility to just write python code that does it. Chances are that the code would be cleaner and easier to understand than transformation schema description.

I wish considered this approach more seriously couple of days ago.

Answer (score 2):

I found `pyjq` library very magical, you can feed it a `template` and `json` file and it will map it out for you.

https://pypi.org/project/pyjq/

The only thing that is annoying about it was the requirements I have to install for it, it worked perfect on my local machine, but it failed when I tried to build it failed to build dependencies for lambda an aws.

Comment: Were you able to resolve the dependency in AWS lambda runtime? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: I figured out what the issue was, I was building the artifact in a different python version and the Lambda had a different runtime. I was also getting the same error if I was building on a mac. It needs to be build in the exact python version and a Linux environment.